# Can't change MS Exchange Server 2010 email display name

Tags: c#, outlook-2010, exchange-server-2010

I'm trying to create a simple email notification program, with a editable display name.

```
 MailMessage mail = new MailMessage();
 mail.From = new MailAddress(from, fromSenderName);
```

Actually the code works just fine in other mail servers like Thunderbird and MailEnable it's with MSExchange that i'm having trouble with. It seems that it always uses the display name that was set in the server and it can't be modified through code, unlike the others where the display name can be overwritten through code.